# force pam to return success

Tags: kernel, login, services, systemd, pam

I want to be able to login (without systemd-user-sessions.service running, is it possible?).

I masked the systemd-user-sessions.service, rebooted, but PAM wont let me in (I can login in tty1 though): "system is booting up. see pam_nologin(8)".

Comment: bump - help anyone?

Comment: I read here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/systemd-user-sessions.8.html

That the service is the one to create the nologin file.  So I masked it AND stopped it before I reboot. I even checked it and logged out, then in. I could. Why couldn't I after the reboot? Who created this file this time?

Comment: OK I've read here: http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_nologin

    it says:
    "Note, the use of successok module argument causes the module to return PAM_SUCCESS and as such would break such a configuration - failing sufficient modules would lead to a successful login because the nologin module succeeded."

    so I did ( /etc/pam.d/login ):   'auth       sufficient  nologin.so'

    Still getting "system is booting up. see pam_nologin(8)" at login screen after reboot.

    So I tried:     'auth       sufficient  nologin.so  successok'

    And still. Why?

Comment: OK Ive finally made it. I want to say thanks to god and to the people who wrote the useful guides out there, it could be anyone. Ive learned in all this process many new things as 'grep' and 'find' command, and reload my memory to other things such as mounting a usb in console. also Ive learned many new options as for 'cp' command.  This was a long journey, and the answer was so simple at the end.

Comment: Thanks to everyone here: http://serverfault.com/questions/134471/success-n-control-syntax-in-pam-conf-pam-d-files

and here: http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=23458

here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LightDM

here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211066/how-do-you-get-pam-succeed-if-so-to-recognize-service-user

here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1043212

http://serverfault.com/questions/644226/how-do-pam-advanced-options-work-exactly/645625#645625?newreg=4a960bceb3c248f1b2ff62cb12bb808d

Comment: here: http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_nologin.html

here: https://forums.proftpd.org/smf/index.php?topic=11121.0

here: http://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=4079

here: http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_nologin

big thanks to them: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Reference_Guide/s1-pam-format.html

and a bigger one to: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:PAM/Service_files

and thanks to google translate!

Final thanks to god (Yea I believe in him, as he believed in me ^.^ )